# Working with complicated immutable objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I have multidimensional array that I would like to have immutable. However I am still not quite sure how am I supposed to work with multidimensional immutable objects.

Lets say that I have structure similar to this one:

```
// data
{
    // item
    {
        name: someName,
        todos: [
            { id: 1, name: todoName },
            { id: 2, name: todoName2 }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I extract unique list of todos?

```
// Saving todos
let uniqueTodos = []
// Saving ids of todos
let saved = []

// I want to make data immutable list
data.forEach(item => {
  item.todos.forEach(todo => {
    if (saved.indexOf(todo.id) === -1) {
      saved.push(todo.id)
      todos.push(todo)
    }
  })

})
return todos
```

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Look at using the filter prototype method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

As for handling unique objects, I assume you mean unique by name. Before adding a todo to the array, just iterate through it really quick to see if the name already exists? It's not optimal but would work. If you need speed consider a different data structure to store todos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are confusing two related concepts: [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) - a technique which can be used in JS vs [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) - a library to make the former easy.

Here's an example of both (dataset is corrected a bit to valid JS and to include a duplicate todo):

```js
const data = {
  item: {
    name: 'someName',
    todos: [
      { id: 1, name: 'todoName' },
      { id: 2, name: 'todoName2' },
      { id: 2, name: 'todoName2' },
    ],
  },
}


console.info(
  'immutable unique todos:',
  data.item.todos.map((todo) => ({ ...todo, }))
)

console.info(
  'Immutable.js unique todos:',
  Immutable.fromJS(data).getIn(['item', 'todos']).toSet().toJS()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/immutable.js/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Immutable.js [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/).